# Where is RAX-ARGOFFSET defined?

Tags: linux, source, assembly

In Linux 3.16, in asm/x86/kernel/entry_64.S, the following line references `RAX-ARGOFFSET` (also see [[src](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S?v=3.16#L424)]):

```
424         movq %rax,RAX-ARGOFFSET(%rsp)
```

But I can not find where `RAX-ARGOFFSET` is defined in anywhere in the linux source tree.?

Comment: https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/1/14/896 mey lead to an answer. Looks like there was a massive cleanup of `ARGOFFSET` usage...

Comment: In 3.16 (which is my working version), since it is referenced, it must be defined somewhere in the same version, right? (even it is set to zero)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RAX` and `ARGOFFSET` are defined in [`calling.h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/calling.h?v=3.16), lines [70](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/calling.h?v=3.16#L70) and [85](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/calling.h?v=3.16#L85) respectively.

Comment: oh, it's not dash, it's a minus ...